# Testing secured EJBs with Arquillian

Tags: testing, ejb, integration-testing, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I made some first steps with Arquillian and get it starting and some simple tests like testing DI etc are working. However, I need to test EJBs that are secured (RolesAllowed) adn I didn't find any solution till now. Further, I have a book regarding Testing with Arquillian and WildFly - the topic about security etc is not mentioned at all - not with a single word. I have also another two books regarding Java EE development where testing is also mentioned, however, always without involving security... I don't need any code just few tips what is required in order to get it working...

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/support.

BR,
Erno

Comment: I have an old demo at [arquillian-security-demo](https://github.com/sfcoy/demos/tree/master/arquillian-security-demo), but I've not updated it in a while

Comment: Thanks a lot - it works with you code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to test entire request and issue login before request (If you are doing so called client tests. If you are doing this, your IT class would probably have @RunAsClient annotation).

If you don't have @RunAsClient, you can try to mock the session with the desired roles.

Comment: Thanks Martin! Currently I do not have any client tests. I'll try both versions and post the status here afterwards.